# UITextView - how to define, that a word is the last word in a line

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitextview

I have a TextView and I need to add a button above each word with the same size and the same font of the button title as in current word. This code works, but if line has one word for example it does not.

```
.h 
@interface Text2ButtonsViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextView *sourceText;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *sourceText;

.m

-(IBAction) processText {

    for (UIView *button in [self.sourceText subviews]) {
        if (button.tag == 33) 
            [button removeFromSuperview];
    }

    NSString *sourceString = [NSString stringWithString:self.sourceText.text];

    NSArray *sourceArray = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    CGSize spaceSize = [@" " sizeWithFont:self.sourceText.font];

    float textPadding = 8.0f;

    float stepX = textPadding;
    float stepY = textPadding;
    CGRect buttonFrame;

    for (NSString *string in sourceArray) {

    UIButton *actButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    actButton.backgroundColor  = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

    [actButton setTitle:string forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    actButton.titleLabel.font = self.sourceText.font;
    CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithFont:self.sourceText.font];
    actButton.tag = 33;
    //if summary width of all buttons and spaces are greater than 
    if (stepX + stringSize.width + textPadding > self.sourceText.frame.size.width) {
        stepX = textPadding;
        stepY = stepY + stringSize.height;
    }
    buttonFrame = CGRectMake(stepX, stepY, stringSize.width, stringSize.height);

    stepX = stepX + stringSize.width + spaceSize.width;
    actButton.frame = buttonFrame;

    [self.sourceText addSubview:actButton];

    }

}
```

How to define that the word is the last one in the line of UITextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do a simple condition checking here.

```
NSArray *sourceArray = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

if ([sourceArray count] == 0 && [sourceString length] != 0) {

    sourceArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sourceString];
}
```

**Edit:**

TextView will contain both white space and new line characters. So you can use the `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:` method to separate the text. Just use,

```
NSArray *sourceArray = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whiteSpaceAndNewLineCharacterSet]];
```

I hope this should work.

Comment: sorry, but I don't catch what you mean. If [sourceArray count] == 0, it means that my source string is empty. And [sourceString count] should not work.

Comment: @Michael, Yes. If the textView contains more than one word, there will be space `@" "` between those words, and `[sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` will return those words as an array. But if your textView contains only one word, there will be no space in the text, so `[sourceString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]` will return `nil`. So, `[sourceArray count]` will be `0`. In that case, if `[sourceString count]` is not `0`, then there is a word in the textView. Right? This is how the if statement `if ([sourceArray count] == 0 && [sourceString count] != 0)` works ;-)

Comment: @EmptyStack First of all thank you that you pay an attention to my question. But NSString class has no method count. It's my fault that my question was not clear. I mean that if I have a text like "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla" - it works. In case the text is "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla\nbla\n bla bla" - it does not. I need to get notification that UITextView started new line with the current word.

Comment: @Michael, Yeah. Sorry that is `[sourceString length]`

Comment: @EmptyStack Yesterday I also found that componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: is the best way to split words and lines. My new code is bellow. Now it works fine either for empty lines and for lines without \n. Of course I'm going to test it. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController {

    UITextView *sourceText;
    UIView *buttonHolder;
}

@implementation DetailViewController

- (IBAction) processText {

    self.buttonHolder.hidden = NO;

    self.sourceText.editable = NO;

    self.buttonHolder.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.sourceText.contentSize.width, self.sourceText.contentSize.height); 

    NSLog(@"self.buttonholder.frame = %@", NSStringFromCGRect (self.buttonHolder.frame) );

    if ([[self.buttonHolder subviews] count] !=0) {
        for (UIView *button in [self.buttonHolder subviews]) 
            [button removeFromSuperview];

    }

    CGSize spaceSize = [@" " sizeWithFont:self.sourceText.font];

    float textPadding = 8.0f;

    float stepX = textPadding;
    float stepY = textPadding;
    CGRect buttonFrame;
    CGSize wordSize;
    NSString *sourceString = [NSString stringWithString:self.sourceText.text];

    float lineHeight = [sourceString sizeWithFont:self.sourceText.font].height;

    NSArray *linesArray = [sourceString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    for (NSString *line in linesArray) {

        NSArray *wordsInLine = [line  componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        for (NSString *word in wordsInLine) {

            UIButton *actButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

            actButton.backgroundColor  = [[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5];

            [actButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [actButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

            [actButton setTitle:word forState:UIControlStateNormal];

            [actButton addTarget:self action:@selector(workWithWord:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            actButton.titleLabel.font = self.sourceText.font;

            wordSize = [word sizeWithFont:self.sourceText.font];
            actButton.tag = 33;

            if (stepX + wordSize.width + textPadding > self.sourceText.frame.size.width) {
                stepX = textPadding;
                stepY = stepY + lineHeight;
            }

            buttonFrame = CGRectMake(stepX, stepY, wordSize.width, lineHeight-lineHeight/10.0);
            actButton.frame = buttonFrame;

            stepX = stepX + wordSize.width + spaceSize.width;

            [self.buttonHolder addSubview:actButton];

        }

        stepX = textPadding;
        stepY = stepY + lineHeight;

    }

}
```